# Delphi XE2: iterate actions in a TAcionManager object

Tags: delphi, iterator, action

I was wondering if there is a way to iterate through **TActions** in a **TActionManager** without the classic for i:= 0 to... but using a iterator in a code like

```
for (action in actionManager.actions) do
begin
...
end;
```

It doesn't work. 
I've tried a lot, always with the same result.

Is it impossible or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!
M.

Comment: When you say something "doesn't work", it helps if you explain in what way it didn't work. Sometimes that information is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "it doesn't compile". Command "for (action in MainActionManager.Actions) do" raise a compiler error "E2029 '[' expected but ')' found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enumerator provided by an action manager provides actions typed as `TContainedAction`. And it is provided by the action manager class so that you can enumerate an action manager directly. Your code attempts to iterate over `ActionManager.Actions` and that could not be possible because `Actions` is an indexed property. You can't iterate over one of those.

So your code needs to look like this:

```
var
  Action: TContainedAction;
....
for Action in ActionManager do
begin
  ....
end;
```

You may need to up-cast using `as` if you want to access properties that are declared in descendents of `TContainedAction`.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this way but I used "for (action in MainActionManager) do" and Delphi didn't compile because of the brackets.